# How to access items class Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a persistent issue on the scrapy projects I start.

Wherever I put `items.py`, it seems not to be recognized inside the spider. I must be missing something.

My project is named `scrapybot`.

To summarize, I have:

```
scrapybot
├──scrapybot 
   ├──__init__.py
   ├──core.py
   ├──custom_middlewares.py
   ├──middlewares.py
   ├──pipelines.py
   ├──settings.py
   ├──spiders
      ├──__init__.py
      ├──amazon_bot.py
      ├──ebay_bot.py
      ├──items.py
```

I want to put `items.py` into the `spider` folder and import it like this:

```
>>> from spiders.items import ScrapybotItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spiders'
```

Or like this:

```
>>> from items import ScrapybotItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'items'
```

Do you know why I can't use imports this way? Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the name of the top level package: `scrapybot`.

Try like this:

```
>>> from scrapybot.spiders.items import ScrapybotItem
```